# How to simplify $(\sin\theta-\cos\theta)^2+(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Simplify: $(\sin \theta − \cos \theta)^2 + (\sin \theta + \cos \theta)^2$

Answer choices:

- 1
- 2
- $ \sin^2 \theta$
- $ \cos^2 \theta$

I am lost on how to do this. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta =1$? If so, you have to write down the two squares and you get $2$.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and try [asking better questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) in the future.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

1) Expand : $(a+b)^2$ and $(a-b)^2$ for all real numbers $a$ and $b$.

2) What is the value of $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x)$ for all real number $x$ ?

Comment: Is it 1? I think I got it

Comment: Yes $\sin^2 (x) + \cos^2 (x) =1$. Now if you expand correctly $(a-b)^2 + (a+b)^2$, you can find the correct answer.

Comment: so 1+1 to get 2

Comment: $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$? I don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is multiply it out.

$(\sin{\theta} - \cos{\theta})^{2} + (\sin{\theta} + \cos{\theta})^{2}$

$= (\sin{\theta} - \cos{\theta})(\sin{\theta} - \cos{\theta}) + (\sin{\theta} + \cos{\theta})(\sin{\theta} + \cos{\theta})$

$= \sin^{2}{\theta} - 2\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta} + \cos^{2}{\theta} + \sin^{2}{\theta} + 2\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta} + cos^{2}{\theta}$

$=\sin^{2}{\theta} + \cos^{2}{\theta} + \sin^{2}{\theta}+ cos^{2}{\theta}$

$= 1 + 1$

$= 2$

Comment: it was a practice ACT question out of this ACT book I have, haha. Thank you though!

Comment: @tiffany Ok, I removed my suggestion about the homework from my answer.  Some people like to post homework questions on here without putting any effort into understanding the problem or solution.  I wanted to make sure you'd ask questions if you had any.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
&\phantom{=}\left(\sin x-\cos x\right)^2+\left(\sin x+\cos x\right)^2\\
&=\sin^2x-2\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x+\sin^2x+2\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x\\
&=2\sin^2x+2\cos^2x\\
&=2\left(\sin^2x+\cos^2x\right)\\
&=2
\end{align}$$